# iPhone 5 Music Playlist Missing

Tags: itunes, iphone

I deleted some playlists on my iPhone 5 to make some space for some apps. But the playlists are not in iTunes. I didn't delete the playlist from iTunes, but when I synced my iPhone with my iTunes, and I checked the playlists to re-sync them, they were missing.

Answer (score 1):

This is how syncing works. If you delete the playlist from your phone, it gets removed from iTunes the next time they are synced.